# Enable module modification in virtualenv

Tags: python, shell, pip, pypi, django-apps

I have 10 django projects that use over 50 django apps. Each app is separated in its own project and added to pypi and is getting use by few project. Every thing if fine except every time i work on a project and i want to change some code that is in one of my modules (that happens a lot) I have to open the module project, make my changes, test and publish to pypi then come back to my project update requirements.txt file and get the updated module from pip.

I'm looking for a way to be able to edit module right away from all of my projects. For example instead of getting it from pypi i want to get it from git and be able to commit to the git repository in my venv folder!

I know it seems a little bit crazy but i could save a lot of time! publisher and user of all of the modules is me so I don't mind the user to be able to change as well.

Any thought or suggestion will be appreciated. Also any none pip solution will be fine as well like writing a custom shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about editing in your venv folder, which I think is not a good practice, but you can install from github by pip. You can use 'pip install git+https://github.com/urltoproject/repository.git'. Fill in the necessary details yourself of course. This also works with other systems like gitlab. You could have a separate development requirement file and a production requirement file to separate the two environments, or you install on the commandline directly with pip.

Comment: I know about this but when pip gets a package from git it doesn't include .git directory anywhere in venv directory so it's still not editable. I think in general library development what I'm trying to do is not right but in my case It really help me speed things up. Thanks anyway

Comment: Okay, so why not install from your local folder. Pip install also works with a local path. Then you don't have to push or even commit. You could run it after every edit you do an maybe even automate it with a little bash script or so. I still would not recommend editing in the venv folder.